# Is there a way to generate TypeScript React components based on templates by API?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, generator, tooling, plop

I would like to generate Typescript React pages or components by using an API and not a CLI tool (like Plop.js) offers for example. The idea is to generate those components from templates based after a tool is run and it should happen behind the scenes without user interacting with the default CLI tools that they usually come in.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have come across [Hygen](https://github.com/jondot/hygen) and used their setup that was noted down in the [Readme](https://github.com/jondot/hygen#build-your-own) to setup an API for generating custom components without interacting with any default CLI tools.

Answer (score 0):

You can use http://json2ts.com/ for this issue.
Or also there is package
https://www.npmjs.com/package/json-to-ts

Comment: Thanks, this is cool but seems it only does interfaces, can’t really generate any functional React components with this.